# Where does stash store comments on pull requests

Tags: bitbucket-server

When you comment on a pull request in stash or add comments to certain lines of a file in the diff where do these things get stored? Are they locked away in a database somewhere or does stash store them in the git repository using something like git-notes ?

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in the database of Stash.

Comment: That gives me a sad. So if you ever transition off stash  all that useful discussion leaves with it.

Comment: @chrisortman There's a very nice API on the off chance you need to get your data out.